# Remove partition and restore the space without erasing

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition

Time ago I split  the hard drive (500gb) in two partitions (250 each), now I don't need them anymore, so I have first erased successfully one partition and now I have still the second one (Mac HD 2)

See the image attached

[image]

What I need now is to reapply the 250 gb I have gained from deleting to the Mac HD2, how is it possible? I am in the situation that I don't want erase it but I need the 250 gb left there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disk utility can't resize the last partition on a drive.
One way would be to use GParted to move the partition and then resize it.

1. Boot the Mac with a Ubuntu Live CD.
2. Run GParted and move the second partition to the beginning of the free space;
3. Reboot to Mac OS X.
4. Verify and repair the external disk with Disk Utility. It found a minor error on the volume header of the second partition.
5. Resize the second partition to the end of free space.

In your case it's a bit easier, since you're only occupying half of the drive.

1. Create a new partition in the empty space
2. Clone the second partition to the first one
3. Delete the 2nd partition
4. Resize the 1st partition

Comment: I have a problem cloning the second partition to the first one, here the screenshot http://it.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2q20cd0&s=8#.VPtcY4GG8X0 . It says that the source volume is for writing and reading and it can not be desactivated that's why it can not be copied in block

Comment: Can you not simply install OS X on the first partition and then use the Migration Assistant that appears at the end of the installation process to transfer everything across from the second partition? Then you can follow steps 3 and 4 that Kevin mentioned above, deleting the second partition and then resizing the first to use the whole drive.

Comment: Is it the drive you boot from? If yes, boot from another drive , internet recovery, usb drive, anything will do